# Problems with swift 5 override func viewWillAppear

Tags: swift, xcode

So I'm an absolute beginner with xcode 11.4 / swift 5.
I found a tutorial on youtube where I wanted to program.

Here I have a problem that the viewtable is not updated after a new entry.

The database was created successfully and the entries that were entered are also displayed. But as I said, as soon as you create a new entry, you won't see it.

Can you help me find the bug?

Thanks a lot

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // MARK: - Outlet

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    // MARK: - View - Lifecylce

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self

        tableView.dataSource = self
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


        CoreDataManager.shared.loadItems()


        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



   // MARK: - TableView methodes

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return CoreDataManager.shared.getNumberofItems()
        }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


        let todo = CoreDataManager.shared.getTodoItems(index: indexPath.row)


        cell.textLabel?.text = todo.name
        return cell
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {


    static let shared = CoreDataManager()


    var todos = [Todo]()



     let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    private init() {
        loadItems()
    }



     func createObj(name: String) {


        let todo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Todo", into: context) as! Todo


        todo.name = name



        todo.completed = false


        saveContext()

    }


    func loadItems() {


        let request = NSFetchRequest<Todo>(entityName: "Todo")


        do {

            todos = try context.fetch(request)

        } catch  {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Count Array

    func getNumberofItems() -> Int {
        return todos.count
    }


    func getTodoItems(index: Int) -> Todo {
        return todos[index]
    }


     func saveContext(){


        do {

            try context.save()

        } catch  {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to reload the table view every time you update it

Comment: Where do you call `createObj`? The `CoreDataManager` class makes no sense because after creating the new object you have to add it to `todos` and tell the table view to insert the row. But there is no reference to the table view. Forget the singleton and put the Core Data code into the view controller.